# WooCommerce Check cart for coupons

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to check the cart to see if it contains any specific coupons, among other things, but it always returns false.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'display_extra_fields_after_billing_address' , 10, 1 );
function display_extra_fields_after_billing_address () {
    // Check if a pre-order product is in the cart
    $preorder_in_cart = false;
    $coupon_codes = array('vip15', 'vip20');
     
    // Loop through all products in the Cart        
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
     
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        
        if( 'yes' === $product->get_meta( '_ywpo_preorder' ) ) {
            $preorder_in_cart = true;
            // break;
        }   
        
        // Checks if the coupons are in the cart
        if(in_array($coupon_codes, WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons() )){
            echo 'found';
        } else {
            echo 'not found';
        }
        
    }
}
```

It works if I check a single coupon though.

```
$coupon_codes = 'vip15';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WC_Cart::get_applied_coupons()` returns an array of coupons that are applied to your cart.

In order to check multiple coupons, variable `$coupon_codes` should be an array. You can then loop through the `$coupon_codes` and check each coupon code.

`in_array()`'s first parameter must be a string.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'display_extra_fields_after_billing_address' , 10, 1 );
function display_extra_fields_after_billing_address () {
    // Check if a pre-order product is in the cart
    $preorder_in_cart = false;
    $coupon_codes = array('vip15', 'vip20');  // or $coupon_codes = array('vip15');
        
    foreach($coupon_codes as $coupon_code) {
        // Checks if the coupons are in the cart
        if(in_array($coupon_code, WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons() )){
            echo 'found';
        } else {
            echo 'not found';
        }
    }
}
```